# Virtual inheritance using empty classes

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell the exact reason for the output of the following code in C++ ?The output that I received for the  code is included in header comments. What does it have to do with virtual table and v pointer.

```
/* sizeof(Empty) 1                                                                                
 sizeof(Derived1) 1 
 sizeof(Derived2) 8 
 sizeof(Derived3) 1 
 sizeof(Derived4) 16 
 sizeof(Dummy) 1
*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Empty
{};

class Derived1 : public Empty
{};

class Derived2 : virtual public Empty
{};

class Derived3 : public Empty
{    
char c;
};

class Derived4 : virtual public Empty
{
char c;
};

class Dummy
{
 char c;
};

int main()
{

    cout << "sizeof(Empty) " << sizeof(Empty) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived1) " << sizeof(Derived1) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived2) " << sizeof(Derived2) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived3) " << sizeof(Derived3) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(Derived4) " << sizeof(Derived4) << endl;    
    cout << "sizeof(Dummy) " << sizeof(Dummy) << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: [Output is slightly different on ideone](http://ideone.com/1PZ8b4)
[However, g++ via coliru agrees with you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bc0dc89c3fb717f)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972548/virtual-dispatch-implementation-details

Comment: @Rndp13: Please stop adding irrelevant and useless tags to everything.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, even a class with no members must have a non-zero size. The standard insists on that. Otherwise *pointer arithmetic* and arrays would not work as an array of a zero-sized class would have all its elements in the same place!

The fact that the other sizes differ may well be due to a v-table. But that is not mandated explicitly in the standard, so is a manifestation of the way your compiler is dealing with things.

Note also that polymorphism requires at least one virtual method to be defined in a base class. This accounts for `sizeof(Derived1)` being the same size as the base class.

Comment: Could the v-table be omitted while retaining standard compliance in this case? In other words, could the compiler ignore the `virtual` inheritance, since there are no fields nor virtual methods in the base class?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in the size is because of `vptr` added by the compiler.

`sizeof(Derived1) = 1`, it is because as per C++ standards empty class always occupies 1 byte of memory.

`sizeof(Derived2) = 8`, Since it inherits virtual base class Derived1,So a vptr is added by the compiler (`sizeof(vptr) = 8` on a `64` bit machine) and hence the `sizeof(Derived2)` is showing 8 bytes.

`sizeof(Derived3) = 1` because of 1 byte of the `char`.

`sizeof(Derived4) = 16`, internal implementation of Virtual inheritance is completely dependent on the compiler, because of this you are seeing 16 bytes as the size.

`sizeof(Dummy) = 1` Since it contains a single char entity.

Answer (score 2):

`Empty` has size 1 because every object must have a size of at least 1.

`Derived1` has size 1 for the same reason.

`Derived2` has size 8 because your compiler needs 8 bytes for the virtual inheritance (probably a pointer).

`Derived3` has size 1 because your compiler has applied the "empty base class" optimisation.

`Derived4` has size 16 because the 8 bytes needed for the virtual inheritance make the object need 8-byte alignment.

`Dummy` has size 1 because that is the size of a `char`.